# Prove that only one of $x<y,x=y,x>y$ can hold.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that in a partially ordered set, only one of

> $$x<y,x=y,x>y$$

can hold.

My book says if both $x<y$ and $x=y$ hold, then this will imply $x<x$, which is a contradiction (contradicting irreflexivity).

I don't understand how this conclusion was reached. Two elements $x$ and $y$ may have multiple relations existing between them. For example, $\langle 2,4\rangle_R$, where $R$ can be $2<4$, $2|4$, $2$ is the largest even number smaller than $4$, etc. These distinct relations don't interact with each other; they have completely distinct identities.

$<$ and $=$ are also distinct relations between $x$ and $y$. One is reflexive while the other is irreflexive. From these two **distinct** relations, how could one ever conclude that irreflexivity (I still don't know of what relation) is being violated?

Comment: The relation $<$ is by definition irreflexive, which means that $x<x$ is **never** true.  So if you make any assumptions which give the conclusion $x<x$, those assumptions cannot all be true simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=y$ then we can replace $y$ by $x$ everywhere. Therefore $y<x$ is the same as $x<x$.

While it is true that different relations don't necessarily interact with one another, equality is part of the logic (in modern approaches). It is part of the underlying language of mathematics, and it runs deeper than $<$ or $>$.

Comment: Wow. Never for one second did I imagine I could just replace $x$ with $y$ in such highly "formal" set theory.

Comment: Perhaps it would be good for you to study some logic too. One of the axioms of equality in logic is that if $x=y$ then we can make these change of variables without changing the truth values.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "replacing $x$ with $y$": one of the *axioms for equality* is
$$(x=y)\to(\Phi(x)\to\Phi(y))\ ,$$
with certain technical restrictions on the terms appearing in this axiom.  [More details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).

Comment: Aww, I was just going to put that link in the comments of my answer! :-)